# How to filter or Identify URI / Request in preHandle() of HandlerInterceptorAdapter Class

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, servlets

I have a RequestInterceptor class which is registered in InterceptorRegistry.

For every request to the application, I have used the **preHandle()** of **HandlerInterceptorAdapter Class** in **RequestInterceptor Class**, to Log all the request in Database.

My requirement is to avoid some of the URI coming to RequestInterceptor, in short, they are mandatory for application but I don't want to store that URI in Database.

Can you suggest what are the possible approach I can use to filter out the requests?

I thought using property file but this will create overhead in each request to preHandle().

Configuration File :

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
}
}
```

RequestInterceptor Class: I am able to get URI using action variable

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private UserAccessLogsService userAccessLogsService;

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response, Object object) {
  try {
   String fullUrl;

   /*returns the part of the full URL before query string separator character '?' */
   StringBuilder requestURL;
   requestURL = new StringBuilder(request.getRequestURL().toString());

   /*returns the part of the full URL after query string separator character '?' */
   String queryString = request.getQueryString();

   /*returns URI */
   String action = request.getRequestURI();

   /*returns Remote Address */
   String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

   if (queryString == null) {
    fullUrl = requestURL.toString();
   } else {
    fullUrl = requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
   }

   /*returns loged in user */
   Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   String userName = auth.getName();

   UserAccessLogs userAccessLogs = new UserAccessLogs(LocalDateTime.now(), userName, remoteAddress, action, fullUrl);
   userAccessLogsService.save(userAccessLogs);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   LOG.error("Error occurred while adding access logs for user ", e);
  }
  return true;
 }

}
```

For eg: Below are the URI which is coming to application and stored in DB,

**/ui/report/user_access_logs** 
**/ui/report/user_activity** 
**/api/systemuser/search**

Now out of above URI I want this **/api/systemuser/search** not to store in DB

Comment: A simple approach will be to filter the request inside ur code logic is to look if teh string contains [\/api]*[\/systemuser]* pattern and then decide accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude Spring Request HandlerInterceptor by Path-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970179/exclude-spring-request-handlerinterceptor-by-path-pattern)

Comment: Filter using If-else?,  I tried using on the block, just before saving the request, but thought if there can be other possible way

Comment: It will better to use the following methods than manually checking of URL, you can do it using the `addPathPatterns` and `excludePathPatterns`.

Comment: Thanks VPK it worked for me.